# Can't download FinRL package in Google Colab

Tags: python, package

It is the error message:
Collecting gym>=0.17
Using cached gym-0.21.0.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I tried to use:
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install --upgrade wheel
And followed this website steps:
https://ai4finance.medium.com/finrl-for-quantitative-finance-install-and-setup-tutorial-for-beginners-1db80ad39159
But still failed, can anyone help me?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.